# CKEDITOR Event for font size or font family selection

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

My requirement is to find the change or selection event for fontsize or fontfamily dropdown in toolbox.

**Change** event in CKEDITOR works whenever any type of change is made in Editor part whether change is made through typing, paste or toolbox button clicked. I need event to detect only for dropdown like fontsize is selected from fontsize dropdown.

**SelectionChange** event works whenever any text is selected in Editor and any type of change is made on selected text whether through typing, or through toolbox button clicked.

**afterCommandExec** is very much closely related with my requirement like it tells which toolbar button is clicked. Basically, I need which toolbox button is clicked. **afterCommandExec** works with all toolbar buttons except for toolbar items which are shown as dropdown like font-family, font-size.
How should I recognize dropdown type button whenever any selection is made in dropdown type button?

Any help would be appreciated.